# PHP if count, first post not going into row

Tags: php, wordpress

Using WordPress, I have a page to grab the logos of clients from a custom post type.

I want the logos to appear as 2 per row, then 3, then 2, repeating so 2, 3, 2, etc.

My code is mostly working but the first image isn't going into the first row.

```
<div class="container">
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'post_type'  => 'clients',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $count = 0;

        while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
            $client_image = get_field('client_logo');
            $size = 'full';

            if($count == 1){
                echo '<div class="row up-to-2">';
            }
            if($count == 2){
                echo '</div><div class="row up-to-3">';
            }

            if( $client_image ) { ?>
                <div class="col-md-<?php echo ($count == 1 ? 6 : 4); ?>">
                    <div class="client-logo">
                        <a class="news-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $client_image, $size ); ?>
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php }
            $count++;
            endwhile;
            echo '</div>';
            ?>
    </div>
```

I've tried

```
if($count == 1){
    $count = 0;
    echo '<div class="row up-to-2">';
}
```

But doing that causes a loop of rows going into row.

I'm trying to better understand PHP and counts so an explanation would be very helpful!

**UPDATE**

I've managed to get the first item into the row but now the order is 2 1 2, instead of what I desire 2, 3, 2.

```
<div class="container">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'  => 'clients',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $count = 0;
    echo '<div class="row up-to-2">';

    while($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
        $client_image = get_field('client_logo');
        $size = 'full';

        if($count == 2){
            echo '</div><div class="row up-to-3">';
        }
        else if($count == 3){
            echo '</div><div class="row up-to-3">';
        }

        if( $client_image ) { ?>
            <div class="col-md-<?php echo ($count == 1 ? 6 : 4); ?>">
                <div class="client-logo">
                    <a class="news-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $client_image, $size ); ?>
                        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>

        <?php }
        $count++;
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need below logic to apply

```
 <?php

$i = 0;

echo '<div class="row up-to-2">'.PHP_EOL;

foreach( range(0,10) as $key => $value ){

    echo '$value='.$value.PHP_EOL;

    if($i == 1) {
        echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL.'<div class="row up-to-3">'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    $i ++;

    if($i == 5) {
        echo '</div>'.PHP_EOL.'<div class="row up-to-2">'.PHP_EOL;
        $i  = 0;
    }
}
echo '</div>';
```

Output:

```
<div class="row up-to-2">
$value=0
$value=1
</div>
<div class="row up-to-3">
$value=2
$value=3
$value=4
</div>
<div class="row up-to-2">
$value=5
$value=6
</div>
<div class="row up-to-3">
$value=7
$value=8
$value=9
</div>
<div class="row up-to-2">
$value=10
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5aa751f40f35def23fce29cf8ac1262c6344d13c) Go to demo link and hit <kbd>**Execute code**</kbd> button

You need your while loop must be like below

```
<?php
$i = 0;
echo '<div class="row up-to-2">' . PHP_EOL;
while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    $client_image = get_field('client_logo');
    $size = 'full';

    if ($client_image) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-<?php echo($count == 1 ? 6 : 4); ?>">
            <div class="client-logo">
                <a class="news-post-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($client_image, $size); ?>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4></a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php }

    if ($i == 1) {
        echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL . '<div class="row up-to-3">' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $i++;

    if ($i == 5) {
        echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL . '<div class="row up-to-2">' . PHP_EOL;
        $i = 0;
    }
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: I'm probably inputting this incorrectly but it just seems to repeat each logo 5 times and doesn't put anything into rows, do you know how I can incorporate this correctly into my current code? I'm a bit of a PHP newbie.

Comment: Are the PHP_EOL needed? From looking online they are just equivilent to line breaks, removing them doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Yeah they are just line breaks